# grouping arrays into arrays bigquery

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this:

| Order id | Item_id | Availability | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc13 | (F1, F2) | 11-10-2021 |
| 1 | xxx12 | (F1, F3) | 11-10-2021 |
| 2 | xxx12 | (F2, F3) | 13-10-2021 |
| ... | ... |  |  |

I want to group by aggregating the "union" of available locations per order_id, i.e.

| Order id | Item_count | Availability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | (F1, F2, F3) --or (F1, F2, F1, F3), don't mind repeating |
| 2 | 1 | (F2, F3) |

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below simple approach

```
select order_id, count(*) item_count,
  array_concat_agg(availability) Availability
from your_table
group by order_id
```

In case if you want to dedup elements in resulting array - use below

```
select order_id, item_count, 
  array( select distinct * from unnest(Availability)) Availability
from (
  select order_id, count(*) item_count,
    array_concat_agg(availability) Availability
  from your_table
  group by order_id
)
```

Note: I am assuming you have arrays as per wording in your question - so you can use below CTE to test, play with above code

```
with your_table as (
  select 1 order_id, 'abc13' item_id, ['F1', 'F2'] availability, '11-10-2021' date union all
  select 1, 'xxx12', ['F1', 'F3'], '11-10-2021' union all
  select 2, 'xxx12', ['F2', 'F3'], '13-10-2021' 
)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the function `array_concat_agg` thanks!